# 2005 Volkswagen Beetle Alternator cable and fuse box replacement

Tags: vw, fuse-panel, beetle

On fixing the problem of the fuse box getting hot and melting one guy recommended putting a 4 gauge cable from the alternator to the fuse box. Isn't there a wire harness that goes from the alternator to the fuse box?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you determined why the fusebox melted, or is this a suggestion to fix it? If you still don't know **that's** the question you should be asking, in which case add some history and what you've tried so far.